# Primefaces SelectOneMenu items are moving on page scroll

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

In the screenshot we can see that a dialog box with some `selectItems` and when I am scrolling using mouse the complete `selectItems` are moving

[image]
My Sample code:

```
    <div class="row">
            <h:outputLabel for="columnNames" value="Select Column Name:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="columnNames" 
                value="#{employeeGroupList.columnName}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="--- Select ---"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeGroupList.columnNames}"></f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it just add `appendTo="@this"` in the `<p:selectOneMenu>`

```
<p:selectOneMenu appendTo="@this"></p:selectOneMenu>
```

If this won't work you can set the position of the `<p:dialog>` to absolute as workaround

```
<p:dialog style="position: absolute; margin-top: 20px;"></p:dialog>
```

This will fix the problem however if you scroll the dialog will remain at the top.